# Preparing a 2D character to export from Blender to Unity?

Tags: unity, python, blender

I'm an animator for a game currently, and I don't have Unity (can't download due to too much gigs coupled with slow internet,) but the game designer told me I can use Blender to export animations into Unity.

I asked if I needed to prepare multiple files to export, and they told me that I could just have one file with all the animations in it. The game, as stated in the title, is 2D.

My problem now is, how do I turn a rig into an actual character with different animations under it? (Right now I only have an 'idle' animation, but need to make running, jumping, walking, etc.) I mean how do I save this 'idle' animation and work on another animation without overwriting the previously finished animation(s)?

Thank you much

Answer (score 1):

For a 2d game , you should use other instruments to animate the character like Spriter pro , however you can put all the "steps" of the animation in one file and then export it in PNG , then in Unity you can use the "Sprite Editor" to cut the image and make various pieces .
This is the documentation of the Sprite Editor : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html .

Answer (score 0):

Note, I haven't done much work with animations in Unity from Blender.

I believe (in Blender), you create a new animation by going to the Dope Sheet, and then to the Action Editor.  This should allow you to create new actions.  You can then create more animations (make sure to press the F button so that Blender saves the animation even if nothing is currently using it!).  Here's what Blender looks like when selection the action editor:

[image: Dope Sheet -> Action Editor]

When the game designer told you that Unity can have the one file, they mean it.  Unity will take the .blend file (you can send that to them), automatically run it through a fbx exporter (even if you make a change, and then save), and allow you to drop it onto the scene.

Unity will also find the animations that you set up in Blender, and allow the designer to set up the animations to their liking using the animation panel (this is where my knowledge lacks).